# Text disappears when putting ggplot on PowerPoint

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

*Using Mac*

I created a graph using ggplot2 and exported it as a pdf.
All seems ok until I load the pdf into a PowerPoint slide -- for some reason the axis' labels and text disappears.

I sense it's related to the font (which has to be Arial..) but I fail to understand why this happens.

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts()

theme_set(theme_bw())
df <- mtcars

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
      geom_point(
                 aes(col = carb),
                 size = 2,
                 position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = .09),
                 show.legend = F
                 ) +
      geom_hline(
                 yintercept = mean(df$cyl),
                 linetype = "dashed",
                 size = 0.5,
                 colour = "gray80"
                 ) +
      theme(
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid = element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "navy"),
            axis.title = element_text(colour = "navy"),
            axis.text = element_text(colour = "navy"),
            text = element_text(family = "Arial")
            ) +
     labs(y = "hey", x = "jude")

plot(gg)
ggsave("test.pdf", gg ,width = 20, height = 12, units = "cm")
```

Update: removing `text = element_text(family = "Arial")` seems to "solve" the problem but I still need to be able to change the text's font so it's not really helpful.

Comment: According to the top answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231720/insert-vector-based-pdf-to-powerpoint-without-loosing-resolution#231791) powerpoint doesn't use the vector properties of a pdf anyway. A quick workaround for you might be simply exporting as a jpg/tiff and importing that in powerpoint. Or use the EPS format as discussed in the answers to above-mentioned question.

This obviously doesn't solve the actual issue you posted.

Comment: Not sure this will help and can't test it right now, but maybe use `embedFonts()`? This really shouldn't be necessary for a font like Arial, but I figured it's worth a try...

Comment: @4rj4n explained the reason and gave alternative solution.